# Extracting date from another column to use for partition

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, extract

I am uploading some CSV files into a big query table. There is a column called **filename** which is in this format:`sales_2021-09-09T21-27-05_010555Z`

I am trying to upload the data from google cloud storage into a partitioned table in the big query. Could you help me to create the field below there is no date column and I need to extract **date** from **filename**:

```
time_partitioning=bigquery.TimePartitioning(
            type_=bigquery.TimePartitioningType.DAY,
            field="date",  # Name of the column to use for partitioning.
            expiration_ms=7776000000,  # 90 days.
        ),
```

**date** column does not exist, above code is from google cloud tutorial of data upload into bigquery.

The below code gives me what I want (extract date from string) but I am not sure how to use it in the above code to be considered as partitiontime :

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
text = 'sales_2022-09-09T21-27-05_010555Z'
match = re.search(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', text)
date = datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

Comment: The type of your date field is a `timestamp` or a `date` in `Bigquery` ?

Answer (score 0):

To insert a `date` field, with the `Python` `BigQuery` client, you can pass a `String` date with the following format : `2022-09-09` :

```py
import re
from datetime import datetime
text = 'sales_2022-09-09T21-27-05_010555Z'
match = re.search(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', text)
res_date = datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        
# Your date as string to insert to BigQuery and in your partition field.
your_date_str = str(res_date)
```

Comment: Thanks, Mazlum. Actually, my table has a filename column which is a string containing a date. I am going to extract that date and use it as a partition for uploading my table into big query.

Comment: The second bit of code is to show how extract date from the string (fieldname column)

Comment: I don't have any date column, I probably need to create it

Comment: Yes for your table, set the type of your date field with type `date`, then add a partition on this field. 
If you pass a string date as I specified in my answer, normally we will be able to load your csv file to the BigQuery table.

Comment: @Sana have you solved your issue ?

Comment: Not yet. I am trying to create Date column from filename column

Comment: You can create your `Bigquery` table from the `Python` client with `CREATE_IF_NEEDED` param. You can use `autodetect` or give the `Json` schema of your `Bigquery` table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249703/discussion-between-mazlum-tosun-and-sana).